# Start/Stop SVG анимация

Tags: css, css3, html5, svg, анимация

Я хотел бы использовать эту красивую SVG-анимацию, размещенную на CodePen, но я не могу понять, как запустить или перезапустить анимацию:

https://codepen.io/elevaunt/pen/JYRBzJ

У кого-нибудь есть идея, как можно скрыть анимацию, а затем показать и активировать ее одним нажатием кнопки?

```css
svg {
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  margin: 40px auto 0;
}

.path {
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  &.circle {
    -webkit-animation: dash .9s ease-in-out;
    animation: dash .9s ease-in-out;
  }
  &.line {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
    -webkit-animation: dash .9s .35s ease-in-out forwards;
    animation: dash .9s .35s ease-in-out forwards;
  }
  &.check {
    stroke-dashoffset: -100;
    -webkit-animation: dash-check .9s .35s ease-in-out forwards;
    animation: dash-check .9s .35s ease-in-out forwards;
  }
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px 0 60px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  &.success {
    color: #73AF55;
  }
  &.error {
    color: #D06079;
  }
}


@-webkit-keyframes dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes dash-check {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: -100;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 900;
  }
}

@keyframes dash-check {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: -100;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 900;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 130.2 130.2">
  <circle class="path circle" fill="none" stroke="#73AF55" stroke-width="6" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="65.1" cy="65.1" r="62.1"/>
  <polyline class="path check" fill="none" stroke="#73AF55" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="100.2,40.2 51.5,88.8 29.8,67.5 "/>
</svg>
<p class="success">Oh Yeah!</p>

<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 130.2 130.2">
  <circle class="path circle" fill="none" stroke="#D06079" stroke-width="6" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="65.1" cy="65.1" r="62.1"/>
  <line class="path line" fill="none" stroke="#D06079" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="34.4" y1="37.9" x2="95.8" y2="92.3"/>
  <line class="path line" fill="none" stroke="#D06079" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="95.8" y1="38" x2="34.4" y2="92.2"/>
</svg>
<p class="error">Bummer!</p>
```

У кого-нибудь есть идея, как можно скрыть анимацию, а затем показать и активировать ее одним нажатием кнопки?

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Start/Stop SVG Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54278166/7394871) от участника  [@iSofia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3017105/isofia).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/54278166/7394871

Answer (score 2):

Пример в Codepen использует `stroke-dasharray: 1000;`

Это может создать вам проблемы, так как значение взято наугад.

Значение `stroke-dasharray` должно быть равно длине пути.

Я пересчитал длину путей, однако я придерживаюсь той же продолжительности анимации. Вы можете изменить время на что-то другое.

Также: `checkboxes` видны, но на практике вы скрываете эти `checkboxes`.
Я добавил границу к элементу svg, чтобы было понятно, где вы должны нажать.
На практике я бы использовал другой путь, возможно, светло-серый под анимированным путем.

```css
svg {
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  margin: 40px auto 0;
}


.path.circle {
  stroke-dasharray: 390.2px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 390.2px;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset .9s ease-in-out;
  
}
.path.line {
  stroke-dasharray: 82.033px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 82.033px;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset .35s ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: .9s;
  
}
.path.check {
  stroke-dasharray: 99.21px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 99.21px;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset .35s ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: .9s;
  
}
p {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px 0 60px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
}
p.success {
  color: #73af55;
}
p.error {
  color: #d06079;
}


svg{border:1px solid}

#a:checked + svg  .path.circle{stroke-dashoffset: 0;}
#a:checked + svg  .path.check{stroke-dashoffset: 0;}


#b:checked + svg  .path.circle{stroke-dashoffset: 0;}
#b:checked + svg  .path.line{stroke-dashoffset: 0;}
```

```html
<label>
  <input id="a" type="checkbox" />
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 130.2 130.2">
  <circle class="path circle" fill="none" stroke="#73AF55" stroke-width="6" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="65.1" cy="65.1" r="62.1"/>
  <polyline  class="path check" fill="none" stroke="#73AF55" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="100.2,40.2 51.5,88.8 29.8,67.5 "/>
  </svg></label>

<p class="success">Oh Yeah!</p>



<label><input id="b" type="checkbox" />
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 130.2 130.2">
  <circle class="path circle" fill="none" stroke="#D06079" stroke-width="6" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="65.1" cy="65.1" r="62.1"/>
  <line class="path line" id="kk" fill="none" stroke="#D06079" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="34.4" y1="37.9" x2="95.8" y2="92.3"/>
  <line class="path line" fill="none" stroke="#D06079" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="95.8" y1="38" x2="34.4" y2="92.2"/>
</svg></label>
```

Как я уже говорил на практике, я бы использовал другой путь, возможно, светло-серый под анимированным путем. Для этого я сохраняю пути в элементе `<defs>` и использую эти элементы с `<use>`

```css
svg {
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  margin: 40px auto 0;
}


.path.circle {
  stroke-dasharray: 390.2px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 390.2px;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset .9s ease-in-out;
  
}
.path.line {
  stroke-dasharray: 82.033px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 82.033px;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset .35s ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: .9s;
  
}
.path.check {
  stroke-dasharray: 99.21px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 99.21px;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset .35s ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: .9s;
  
}
p {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px 0 60px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
}
p.success {
  color: #73af55;
}
p.error {
  color: #d06079;
}

.base{fill:none;stroke:#d9d9d9;stroke-width:6;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-linecap:round;}


#a:checked + svg  .path.circle{stroke-dashoffset: 0;}
#a:checked + svg  .path.check{stroke-dashoffset: 0;}


#b:checked + svg  .path.circle{stroke-dashoffset: 0;}
#b:checked + svg  .path.line{stroke-dashoffset: 0;}
```

```html
<label>
  <input id="a" type="checkbox" />
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 130.2 130.2">
  <defs>
   <circle id="c"  cx="65.1" cy="65.1" r="62.1"/>
   <polyline id="py" fill="none" points="100.2,40.2 51.5,88.8 29.8,67.5 "/>    
  </defs>
  <g  class="base">
  <use xlink:href="#c"/>
  <use xlink:href="#py"/>
  </g>
  <g fill="none" stroke="#73AF55" stroke-width="6" stroke-miterlimit="10">
  <use class="path circle" xlink:href="#c"/>
  <use class="path check" xlink:href="#py"/>
  </g>
  </svg></label>

<p class="success">Oh Yeah!</p>



<label><input id="b" type="checkbox" />
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 130.2 130.2">
  <defs>
  <line id="l1" x1="34.4" y1="37.9" x2="95.8" y2="92.3"/>
  <line id="l2" x1="95.8" y1="38" x2="34.4" y2="92.2"/>
  </defs>
  
  <g class="base">
  <use xlink:href="#c"/>
  <use xlink:href="#l1"/>
  <use xlink:href="#l2"/>
  </g>
  
  
  <g fill="none" stroke="#D06079" stroke-width="6" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-linecap="round">
  <use class="path circle" xlink:href="#c"/>
  <use class="path line" xlink:href="#l1"/>
  <use class="path line" xlink:href="#l2"/>
  </g>
</svg></label>
  

<p class="error">Bummer!</p>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54278652/7394871) от участника  [@enxaneta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7897395/enxaneta).</sub>